# webpack babel build and external folder issue (k6 typescript)

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs

For a project, I have to create some stress test and I found k6.
The project is made with typescript then I use the template https://github.com/k6io/template-typescript.

My tree is :

```
- project (containing my angular project in typescript)
-- src folder
- k6
-- webpack.config.ts
-- package.json
-- src folder (containing my test files in typescript)
```

k6 is using webpack/babel to transform ts files in js files and I'm not familiar with.

Some of my test import files that are in my project/src folder but I have errors during build.

Error example:

```
ERROR in ../project/src/config-values.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /home/fred/Documents/project/src/config-values.ts: Unexpected token, expected "{" (4:7)

  2 | import { getRandomBoolean } from "./random-values"
  3 |
> 4 | export enum ConfigType {
    |        ^
```

If I copy the files that are in my project folder in my k6 folder, I have no error but I don't want to have to keep update two folders which must be identical.

Despite some research, I haven't found a solution yet and I'm a little bit stuck to import ts files that are outside of my k6 folder.

Here is my webpack config

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const GlobEntries = require('webpack-glob-entries');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: GlobEntries('./src/*test*.ts'), // Generates multiple entry for each test
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  target: 'web',
  externals: /^(k6|https?\:\/\/)(\/.*)?/,
  // Generate map files for compiled scripts
  devtool: "source-map",
  stats: {
    colors: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    // Copy assets to the destination folder
    // see `src/post-file-test.ts` for an test example using an asset
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [{
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
        noErrorOnMissing: true
      }],
    }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    // Don't minimize, as it's not used in the browser
    minimize: false,
  },
};
```

and my package.json

```
{
  "name": "typescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "ssh://git@github.com/k6io/example-typescript.git",
  "author": "Simon Aronsson <simme@k6.io>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.13.16",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.13.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "7.13.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.13.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^2.13.7",
    "@graphql-codegen/client-preset": "^1.0.7",
    "@graphql-codegen/fragment-matcher": "^3.3.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/gql-tag-operations-preset": "^1.6.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/introspection": "2.2.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^2.7.4",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-apollo-angular": "^3.5.4",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-graphql-request": "^4.5.8",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^2.5.4",
    "@types/k6": "~0.35.0",
    "@types/webpack": "5.28.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-alpha.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^9.0.1",
    "gql-tag": "^1.0.1",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "ramda": "^0.28.0",
    "ramda-adjunct": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "webpack": "^5.87.0",
    "webpack-cli": "4.6.0",
    "webpack-glob-entries": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "format": "webpack",
    "codegen": "graphql-codegen --config codegen.ts"
  }
}
```

Do you have an idea to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I don't know if it's the change in my tree structure or the change in my configuration files.

My new tree is

```
- webpack.config.ts
- package.json
- project
- k6
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-ts-babel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.5",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "webpack": "^5.88.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.0",
    "webpack-glob-entries": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "k6": "webpack"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const GlobEntries = require('webpack-glob-entries');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: GlobEntries('./k6/src/*test*.ts'),
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  target: ['web', 'es5'],
  externals: /^(k6|https?\:\/\/)(\/.*)?/,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.ts', '.js' ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'k6/dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
};
```

tsconfig.json in k6 folder

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmit": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "removeComments": true,

    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,

    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,

    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,

    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

I know that my tsconfig removed a lot of typescript verification but it's mandatory as I'm not alone on the project folder and I can't modify all files in it to have no error during build.

Now my k6 tests are working and use the files imported from my project.

Comment: I moved my folder k6 and put webpack config in it, modify path in the config and it's still working.  can tell that it's just the webpack config that resolved my issue.